# How to get the value of the parent li in a nested list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can you help me, I create a nested list like this:

```
<ol>
   <li data-value="1">
        <ol>
           <li data-value="1"></li>
           <li data-value="2"></li>
           <li data-value="3"></li>
        </ol>
   </li>
   <li data-value="3"></li>
   <li data-value="3"></li>
</ol>
```

How can I get the data-value attribute for the parent only?

sample output:
1,3,3

Comment: `.parent().attr('data-value')` maybe?  It's not really clear what your asking.  Do you have some JavaScript that selects a particular `li` somewhere?

Comment: closest will work for you `$(this).closest('li').attr('data-value');`

Comment: .parent wont work because the parent of a nested li is the ol. Use closes as @AmanRawat suggests to find the next li up the dom tree.

Comment: @MarkWalters the element that the OP is asking about is ambiguous.  You assume they are asking about an `li`

Comment: The parent element isn't amibigious, he's asking for the parent li in a nested list, .parent() won't get the parent li but the parent of the current node which in this case will be ol. Also he's after the data atrribute which he shows in his structure as belonging to all the li's

Comment: @Tibrogargan it has to be the `li` OP is asking about, the `ol` doesn't have the data attribute on it

Comment: @Pete no, but the `ol` elements are the *only ones* that actually have a **parent `li`**.   Your assumption is probably correct, but it's still an assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('li').not('li ol li').each(function(){
console.log($(this).attr('data-value'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
   <li data-value="1">
        <ol>
           <li data-value="1"></li>
           <li data-value="2"></li>
           <li data-value="3"></li>
        </ol>
   </li>
   <li data-value="3"></li>
   <li data-value="3"></li>
</ol>
```

Try this one

Comment: @tots see my answer :) similar to this one

Comment: @tots happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple way:

`$('ol > li').not('ol ol li').attr('data-value');`

or in a loop:

```js
$('ol > li').not('ol ol li').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li data-value="1">
    <ol>
      <li data-value="1a"></li>
      <li data-value="2a"></li>
      <li data-value="3a"></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-value="2"></li>
  <li data-value="3"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you are getting value of child `li` not parent

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ol").first().find("> li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li data-value="1">
    <ol>
      <li data-value="1"></li>
      <li data-value="2"></li>
      <li data-value="3"></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-value="3"></li>
  <li data-value="3"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: why `$($("ol")[0])`?

Comment: i believe OP want access only top most `ol` and not the nested one

Comment: what a terrible selector `$($("ol")[0])`

Comment: This does not come close to doing what the OP asked for

Comment: @Pete - you may like this `$.first()`

Comment: @Tibrogargan - you may look at result of this snippet and the the output OP is looking for. I think its almost equal.

Comment: @vijayP that might be correct if the OP wanted all the parent `li`s, but that's not how the question is worded.  Frankly, the question needs to be edited to be less ambiguous.  Didn't notice they added the sample output.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - yes...may be.

Comment: And frankly .... `$('ol').first().children('li').each( (i,v) => console.log(v.dataset.value));` ... `children` is cheaper, so is direct use of `dataset`

Answer (score 0):

You should find the most nearest "parent" li and find its data-value attribute.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$(this).closest('li').attr('data-value');
```

Comment: Add a click handler to one of the leaf `li` nodes and try this.  You might want to change the data-value values to allow easier comparison

Answer (score -1):

Try use jQuery [`.parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function:

```
$(this).parents("[data-testing]:first");
```